# UnknownTimeZoneError with django celery

Tags: django, eclipse, django-celery, pytz

I am developing a Django project in PyDev (eclipse) using the following modules:

```
Django==1.5.1
MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
celery==3.0.21
django-celery==3.0.17
pytz==2013b
```

I installed celery to automate jobs and I added the code below to the bottom of my settings.py.

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

I also added the `djcelery` application to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. When I run my server using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the exception below when accessing my localhost:8000. If I remove the `djcelery` code from my `settings.py` the server runs with no problems. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

```
UnknownTimeZoneError at /
'America/Boston'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: UnknownTimeZoneError
Exception Value:    
'America/Boston'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py in timezone, line 185
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.7.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\twitter-1.9.4-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\twython-3.0.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests_oauthlib-0.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauthlib-0.5.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-3.3.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 22 Jul 2013 22:50:03 -0400
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set TIME_ZONE var to None in settings.py file:

```
TIME_ZONE = None
```